# ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM"

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error, sql-insert

A pretty simple error which I just have no idea about.
Here's the code:

```
INSERT INTO srs1.modulegrades

VALUES (srs1.student.student_id, srs1.modules.module_id, floor(random() * 10))

FROM srs1.student, srs1.modules;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use an insert-select statement:

```
INSERT INTO srs1.modulegrades
SELECT      srs1.student.student_id, 
            srs1.modules.module_id, 
            FLOOR(RANFOM() * 10))
FROM        srs1.student, srs1.modules;
```

Note that implicit joins (having more than table in the `from` clause) are considered deprecated, and you'd properly be better off using an explicit cross join:

```
INSERT INTO srs1.modulegrades
SELECT      srs1.student.student_id, 
            srs1.modules.module_id, 
            FLOOR(RANFOM() * 10))
FROM        srs1.student
CROSS JOIN  srs1.modules;
```

Comment: Thanks, that has worked. Not the way I expected, but that's my logic rather than the code

Comment: I'm now trying to get student_id to only occur 4 times. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Inserting into a relation from existing relation requires a `SELECT` clause. A `values` clause is used to create a relation dynamically for data input into the system.

*thanks to user melpomene for the following:*

[Relevant part of the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html). Note that VALUES ... and query are listed as alternatives; i.e. you can't have both VALUES and SELECT ... FROM.

The following should work for your database:

```
INSERT INTO srs1.modulegrades
  SELECT srs1.student.student_id
       , srs1.modules.module_id
       , floor(random() * 10) 
  FROM srs1.student, srs1.modules;
```

Comment: Relevant part of the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html. Note that `VALUES ...` and **_query_** are listed as alternatives; i.e. you can't have both `VALUES` and `SELECT ... FROM`.

Comment: Thanks @melpomene, I'll add that to my answer.